# Scaling Up of GlusterFS-storage only add new peer without new bricks in Openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

#### Observed behavior

I started with one node Openshift cluster and it successfully deployed master/node and gluster volume. Now I extend Openshift cluster and it was successfully.

but on extending glusterfs volume with below

```
[glusterfs]
10.1.1.1  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]'
10.1.1.2  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]'  openshift_node_labels="type=upgrade"

ansible-playbook -i inventory2.ini /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/openshift-glusterfs/config.yml -e openshift_upgrade_nodes_label="type=upgrade"
```

it only added 10.1.1.2 as peer but volume still has only one brick

Following customization done to start deploy gluster from 1 node {--durability none}

```
openshift-ansible/roles/openshift_storage_glusterfs/tasks/heketi_init_db.yml

- name: Create heketi DB volume
  command: "{{ glusterfs_heketi_client }} setup-openshift-heketi-storage --image {{ glusterfs_heketi_image }} --listfile /tmp/heketi-storage.json **--durability none**"
  register: setup_storage


>gluster peer status
Number of Peers: 1
Hostname: 10.1.1.2
Uuid: 1b8159e4-99e2-4f4d-ad95-e97bc8655d32
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)


gluster volume info

Volume Name: heketidbstorage
Type: Distribute
Volume ID: 769419b9-d28f-4cdd-a8f3-708b6b738f65
Status: Started
Snapshot Count: 0
Number of Bricks: 1
Transport-type: tcp
Bricks:
Brick1: 10.1.1.1:/var/lib/heketi/mounts/vg_4187bfa3eb090ceffea9c53b156ddbd4/brick_80401b43be8c3c8a74417b18ad574524/brick
Options Reconfigured:
transport.address-family: inet
nfs.disable: on
```

#### Expected/desired behavior

I am expecting that on addition of every new node it should create new brick too

#### Details on how to reproduce (minimal and precise)

```
Add nodes in gluster cluster with below commands
ansible-playbook -i inventory2.ini /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/playbooks/openshift-glusterfs/config.yml -e openshift_upgrade_nodes_label="type=upgrade"
```

#### Information about the environment:

- Heketi version used (e.g. v6.0.0 or master):  **OpenShift 3.10**
- Operating system used:  **CentOS**
- Heketi compiled from sources, as a package (rpm/deb), or container:  **Container**
- If container, which container image:  **docker.io/heketi/heketi:latest**
- Using kubernetes, openshift, or direct install:  **Openshift**
- If kubernetes/openshift, is gluster running inside kubernetes/openshift or outside:  **outside**
- If kubernetes/openshift, how was it deployed (gk-deploy, openshift-ansible, other, custom):  **openshift-ansible**

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a node/server does not mean that the brick will also be added to existing 
gluster volume.
You have to add that brick, hosted on new node, to existing volume.
command -

"gluster volume add-brick  host:brick-path commit force"

Not sure if you have provided this command in your automation script or not.